# TypeError 'bool' object not subscriptable

Tags: python, json, parsing

My code is pulling JSON data from an api as such, however I'm having trouble getting my code to read from the JSON objects.

```
url = 'https://api.test.net/Vacancy'
payload = {
    "APIKey": "0000",
    "Action": "GetAllVacancies",
    "Content-Type" : "json",
}

headers = {}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(r.content)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

json_obj = r.json()
for index in json_obj:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO apidata (VacancyName, Department, Location) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (json_obj[index]["VacancyName"], (json_obj[index]["Department"], (json_obj[index]["Location"]))

cursor.close()
```

My JSON response looks like this

```
{ 
   "isError":false,
   "Status":0,
   "Message":"",
   "Result":[ 
      { 
         "VacancyName":"Test Vacancy",
         "VacancyDescription":"test data 123",
         "Location":"location 1",
         "Department":"Finance",
```

However I keep getting the error

> TypeError 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Im trying to pull this JSON data and send it to a database, thanks!

Comment: error should show you which line makes problem and then use `print()` to see values in variables used in this line. It seems you have variable with True/False an you treat it as list so you run something like `True[1]`

Comment: To improve your chances of useful answers, please boil the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: instead of `post( ..., data=json.dumps(payload))` you can use `post(..., json=payload)`

Comment: Why do you expect iterating over *all* keys (``isError``, ``Status``, ``Message``, ``Result``) makes it valid to look up nested keys valid for only *one* key?

Comment: What do you expect `json_obj["isError"]["VacancyName"]` to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at

```
for index in json_obj:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO apidata (VacancyName, Department, Location) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (json_obj[index]["VacancyName"], (json_obj[index]["Department"], (json_obj[index]["Location"]))
```

you loop over keys in `json_obj` and first key is `isError`. so `json_obj[index]` is `False`, thus not subscriptuble and you get error when try to access key ["VacancyName"].

You need to loop over elements in `json_obj["Result"]`

```
for result in json_obj["Result"]:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO apidata (VacancyName, Department, Location) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (result["VacancyName"], result["Department"], result["Location"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object is a `dict`. Iterating over a dict iterates over the keys.

The first key in your object is `"isError"` so when you try to access `json_obj[index]["Department"]` that is equivalent to `(json_obj["isError"]["Department"]` which is `False["Department"]` which gives the error you are seeing.

Please in future include the full error message including the traceback. It makes it a lot easier to answer these questions if you do.